# Keyword 'BuiltIn.Log To Console' expected 1 to 3 arguments, got 8

Tags: robotframework, python-3.8

Getting this error when I try to execute below query after connecting to DB in Robot Framework - Python

```
Connect to DB
  @{queryResults}=  query select * from schema.table where country='BRAZIL';

  log to console  many   @{queryResults}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such keyword as `log to console many` so either you use `Log To Console` and pass as argument list with `$` sign or you use keyword `Log Many` and pass list with `@` sign.